# props of undefined at handleAddOption (app.js:64)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have in my code a simple form where I can alert input data. So In my first class, I define a function. Then I pass that function to another class.

```
class IndecisionApp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.handleAddOption = this.handleAddOption.bind(this)
        this.state = {
            options: ['test1,test2,test3']
        }
    }

    handleAddOption(option) {
        console.log(option)
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <AddOption
                    handleAddOption={this.handleAddOption} 
                 />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class AddOption extends React.Component {

    handleAddOption(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        const option = e.target.elements.option.value.trim()

        if(option) {
         this.props.handleAddOption(option)
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleAddOption}>
                    <input type="text" name="option"/>
                    <button>Add Option</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

 ReactDOM.render(<IndecisionApp />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

This line of code `this.props.handleAddOption(option)` gives me the error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
at handleAddOption (app.js:64)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:1527)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:1566)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:1423)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:1437)
at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:1660)
at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:1682)
at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:2197)
at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:2208)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at forEachAccumulated (react-dom.development.js:2174)
at Object.processEventQueue (react-dom.development.js:2367)
at runEventQueueInBatch (react-dom.development.js:2379)
at Object.handleTopLevel [as _handleTopLevel] (react-dom.development.js:2389)
at handleTopLevelImpl (react-dom.development.js:2028)
at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:14309)
at performFiberBatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:1874)
at stackBatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:1865)
at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:1879)
at Object.batchedUpdatesWithControlledComponents [as batchedUpdates] (react-dom.development.js:1892)
at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:2102)
```

I am binding the **handleAddOption** inside the constructor, so I don't know why I am getting that error. What did I miss?

Thanks,
Theo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `constructor()` inside the `<AddOption />`, too.

```
class AddOption extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.handleAddOption = this.handleAddOption.bind(this)
        ...
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind handleAddOption of class AddOption to this:

```
class AddOption extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleAddOption = this.handleAddOption.bind(this)
}
```